# Automator Stack Like Interface with Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, automator

I've been attempting to create an automator styled interface similar to this:
[image: Automator Interface]

My approach has been a NSTableView with view based cells, but along the way I've met many pitfalls like cell row sizing and interaction troubles, is this the way to go (NSTableView) or is there a better approach I'm missing?

Update: Also I hear that View based table views (rather than cell based) are only on Lion onwards and I'd like to have support for snow leopard; are cell based easy enough to add interaction to or is there a better option?

Comment: NSTableView seems right. NSTableViews can have their row heights dynamically changed, even with animation. So what's the problem?

Comment: I just thought there would be a better solution for a single column variable sized row interface like this, I have to configure a NSTableView a lot to get what I want out of it and I'd rather not.